# Git log print relative revision number

Tags: git, git-log

Is it possible to get `git log` to print the relative revision number, i.e. the number `x` which can be used with e.g. `git show HEAD~x`?

Comment: Something like `git log | git name-rev --stdin` (mentioned at the bottom of the [`git-name-rev` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-name-rev))?

Comment: Yes, that looks promising, but can I get it to only show numbers relative to HEAD, and to stop printing after filling the page?

Comment: I don't know whether/how you can get it to show numbers relative to `HEAD`, but to "stop printing after filling the page", you can use pipe the output to a pager, e.g. `git log | git name-rev --stdin | less`; would that work?

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you! Is there a way to keep the color coding? (I'm on Windows)

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps someone else knows...

Comment: git log --color=always ....

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss Do you mean `git log --color=always | git name-rev --stdin | less`? That doesn't produce the desired result in bash...

Comment: @Jubobs What's the issue? It seems to work in my Git Bash.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss I can't tell about Git Bash, but [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ORDsX.png) is what it looks like in bash.